# screen is not navigating in touchablenativefeedback and also do it matter is component is funtional or class in react nativegation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Result from './components/Result';
import Home from './components/Home';

export default class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
    return (
         <AppContainer />
      )
     }
    }

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
      screen: Home,
   },
Result: {
     screen: Result
   }
  }, {
       initialRouteName: "Result"
  });

  const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

and it **error coming is **

node_modules\expo\AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:25241 Error: `createStackNavigator()` has been moved to `react-navigation-stack`. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

As said by the error, `createStackNavigator()` has been moved to `react-navigation-stack` in react-navigation version 4, so you have to install `react-navigation-stack` separately.

```
npm i react-navigation-stack
```

or

```
yarn add react-navigation-stack
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.